# AutoCompleteDecorator.decorate(combobox); is not working perfectly in JTable

Tags: java, netbeans, jtable, jcombobox, swingx

I'm using A `JCombobox` with `editable = true` in a `JPanel` and using a `JTable` in the same panel with a column that is set to show combobox as its field type. I applied

```
 AutoCompleteDecorator.decorate(cb);
```

to `JCombobox` that is outside the `JTable` and its working perfectly **But** when I applied the same line of code to combobox within jtable which selects the first occurrence of the data that match the key typed.

How can I resolve this issue. Any Suggestion ?

Look at the image below in which the exact item is selected that I typed.

[image]

And this is the image of combobox within `JTable`.

[image]

When I press  <kbd>w</kbd>  key it select the first occurrence `windy` and set it in the cell.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't posted a code, but have you checked which TableCellEditor you use?

You might have used DefaultTableCellEditor. Change it to ComboBoxCellEditor if that's the case.

example:

```
JCombobox cmbItems = new JComboBox();
cmbItems.addItem("choice1");
cmbItems.addItem("choice2");
cmbItems.addItem("choice3");
AutoCompleteDecorator.decorate(cmbItems);
TableColumn colWithCmb = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0);
colWithCmb.setCellEditor(new ComboBoxCellEditor(cmbItems));
```